# Difference between tf.GradientTape and backprop.GradientTape

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

When looking at the `OptimizerV2` code in Tensorflow 1.15 I noticed that they use `backprop.GradientTape` to compute the gradient.

I can't find any online reference to this class, only to `tf.GradientTape`.
What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference, it is [the same class](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f99cd711a9629fbdd801aaed2a5cae54c0daa870/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py#L720):

```
@tf_export("GradientTape", "autodiff.GradientTape", v1=["GradientTape"])
class GradientTape(object):
  ...
```

TensorFlow internals generally do not use the public API and import other internal modules directly.